# Proper collection in Redis that will allow updating and deleting by field

Tags: redis, zset

I want to store a collection of weather forecasts as JSON objects in redis:

```json
{
  "city":"London",
  "weather":"SUNNY",
  "lastPrediction": "..",
  "source":"..."
}
```

Each item has a unique city name and there would be up to tens of thousand weather forecasts.

I want to be able to add those to the collection, find and update a single item by the city and remove it by the city as well.

I wonder which structure should I use - I especially do not know how to update and delete entries by a certain field.

Comment: Did you check the RediSearch module for Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Since each item has an unique "city", [hash](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-hashes) works fine for your case.

- you may set multiple items with [HSET](https://redis.io/commands/hset) (If your redis version is < 4.0.0 - then please check [HMSET](https://redis.io/commands/hmset))
- you may access to the individual fields with [HGET](https://redis.io/commands/hget)
- update your fields with `HSET` again, and delete your fields with [HDEL](https://redis.io/commands/hdel)
- if you want to get all the fields then you use [HGETALL](https://redis.io/commands/hgetall)

here is the demo;

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET london weather SUNNY lastPrediction "foo" source "foobar"
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET london weather
"SUNNY"
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL london
1) "weather"
2) "SUNNY"
3) "lastPrediction"
4) "foo"
5) "source"
6) "foobar"
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET london weather CLOUDY
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET london weather
"CLOUDY"
127.0.0.1:6379> HDEL london source
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL london
1) "weather"
2) "CLOUDY"
3) "lastPrediction"
4) "foo"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Please consider redis keys and fields are case sensitive.

Comment: and what if I want to get multiple cities in one operation?

Comment: @pixel you may call `hget` for each cities that you want. or you can use lua scripting.

Comment: @Esroy thing is I don't know city names so I need something like scan or get all (all keys, not all values for one key). I use redis for other purposes so I can't query all the keys globally

Comment: @pixel then you need a secondary index to keep track of list of cities. whenever you create a city hash(with name x,y,z) you need to push those cities into a separete "redis set" and you may fetch it from there. The thing is it will take some time and will may block redis when you try get all city names from a separete key. can you explain your case more ? "you don't know city names so you will get all the city names at once and query all the weather forecast for every single one of them ? "

Comment: I want to have an option to query all the cities that are in redis. But I think I will just have keys as prefixes "forecast_cityName" and use `SCAN` to fetch them